# JPanel inside a JScrollPane inside a JPanel inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JFrame which I add a custom JPanel class to. That JPanel class has two member variables, another JPanel and a JScrollPane.

I construct the JScrollPane using the child JPanel, I then try to add the JScrollPane to the parent JPanel in hopes I would have a scrollable custom JPanel.

I have a big thin white line infront of all my components and their is no scrolling. Any ideas?

```
public class CreateGamePanel extends JPanel
{   
    private JLabel pwLabel;
    private JTextField password;

    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private JPanel area;

    public CreateGamePanel()
    {
        area = new JPanel();
        area.setLayout(new BoxLayout(area,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        jsp = new JScrollPane(area);

        pwLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        password = new JTextField();

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            area.add(new JButton("Hello"));
        }

        area.add(pwLabel);
        area.add(password); 

        add(jsp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        CreateGamePanel cp = new CreateGamePanel();

        f.add(cp);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default policy of scroll bars in a JScrollPane is to only show up when the size of the child component doesn't fit inside the pane. What is happening in your code is that the JScrollPane's parent is the game panel and is automatically being resized to contain the entire JScrollPane and its child instead of being forced to fit in the available space in the JFrame. To do that you just have to be more specific on setting up your layouts.

Try this code, for example:

```
public class CreateGamePanel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel pwLabel;
    private JTextField password;

    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private JPanel area;

    public CreateGamePanel()
    {
        area = new JPanel();
        area.setLayout(new BoxLayout(area,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        jsp = new JScrollPane(area);

        pwLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        password = new JTextField();

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            area.add(new JButton("Hello"));
        }

        area.add(pwLabel);
        area.add(password);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());    // Change default LinearLayout to BorderLayout
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);    // Add child to the central area of BorderLayout
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        CreateGamePanel cp = new CreateGamePanel();

        f.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // Make sure the game panel will be resized to fit frame
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The trick here is that contents in the BorderLayout.CENTER part of the BorderLayout are resized to fit the available space in the parent.